# An error occurred after encoding with h264_nvenc

Tags: ffmpeg, nvenc

1373x768 yuv420p picture

1. The ffmpeg api(avcodec_send_frame, avcodec_receive_packet) will write the avpacket-data data to the file after the encoding is successful, and then decode t using ffmpeg command line, save AvPacket::data, the resulting picture is not normal
2. Directly use ffmpeg command line encoding, and then decode, the resulting picture is normal

decodec command： ffmpeg -i out.h264 -ss 0 -frames:v 1 output_frame.png
ecodec command： ffmpeg -s:v 1376x768 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i input.yuv -c:v h264_nvenc out.h264

exception picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kpky.png)

Encoder Settings for api calls:

```
    _encodecH264 = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("h264_nvenc");
    _encodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(_encodecH264);
    _encodecContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    _encodecContext->time_base.num = 1;
    _encodecContext->time_base.den = 25;
    _encodecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    _encodecContext->width = w;
    _encodecContext->height = h;
    _encodecContext->gop_size = 25;
    av_opt_set(_encodecContext->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
    av_opt_set(_encodecContext->priv_data, "profile", "main", 0);
```

Would like to ask why the api call encoding operation result is abnormal？

The first scheme uses the normal 1920x1080 picture